# Connection and hook data is not available in Feathers JS Filter

Tags: feathersjs

From my understanding, within a hook, I should be able to assign data to `hook.params` and then access in a filter via `connection`.

Here are some extracts of my code.

#### Hook

```
module.exports = {
    before: {
        all: [
            function (hook) {
                Object.assign(hook.params, {
                    "message": "testing 123"
                });
                return hook;
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Filter

```
module.exports = function (data, connection, hook) { 
    console.warn("FILTER", connection);
    console.warn("FILTER", hook);
    return data;
};
```

#### Output when service is called

```
FILTER { provider: 'socketio' }
FILTER undefined
```

So, the filter is being hit, but I'm not able to access any useful data to perform filtering against.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Are you using `feathers-sync`?

Comment: Yes, I am. Why?

Comment: It's a bug in `feathers-sync`: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sync/issues/32. I'll fix it once Feathers v3 is released.